# /etc/cron.daily/logrotate error

Tags: debian, cron

После установки vps с debian 7 и isp manager каждый день ночью приходит такой отбойник на почту:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.daily/logrotate: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

В задачах для крона ничего связанного с logrotate нет, файл `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` — пуст.

Comment: потому что он пуст. Попробуйте удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибку можно воспроизвести, если в каталоге, переданном программе *run-parts* в качестве аргумента, присутствует пустой файл с битами исполнимости:

```
$ touch file
$ run-parts .
$ chmod +x file
$ run-parts .
run-parts: failed to exec ./file: Exec format error
run-parts: ./file exited with return code 1
```

решение: удалить этот пустой файл или хотя бы убрать биты исполнимости:

```
$ sudo chmod -x /путь/к/файлу
```

---

> В задачах для крона ничего связанного с logrotate нет

скрипты из `/etc/cron.daily` выполняет программа *run-parts*, запускаемая ежедневно программой *crond* благодаря наличию соответствующей строчки в `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: Стандартно cron.daily подключается в /etc/crontab

Comment: @sercxjo, да, спасибо, что обратили на это внимание: я перечитал вопрос и ответ, и понял, что вторая часть ответа не совсем «в тему». пришлось менять эту вторую часть.